# Servo arduino using eneloop

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, batteries, current

Say if i use 5x eneloop AA batteries to run 6x MG996R servo, will it be good enough since im afraid for the motor if it will burn out. I already read the spec sheet what im afraid is the stall current

[image: Image copyright goes to Edditive im just using it to show an example how it will be used]

Comment: This is really an off-topic *usage* question.  Consider that RC models often have 4-6 of these, and research what battery solution they use... it *used* to be AA NiCd's.  Also realize that if a battery can't supply the current, they'll just move more slowly with reduced torque.  Bear in mind also that 6xAA cannot reliably power an Arduino's regulator, especially when also powering servos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up the data sheet on that servo it says it draws 500-900 mA. Use the higher number, and add 10%. Now you're at ≈1A. To power 5 of them, you'll need ≈5A peak.

Doing a little googling, it sounds like 1A is on the high end for constant current draw on an AA battery. (Eneloops included.) Thus driving 5 of them is asking too much of AA cells.

You'd be better off with 5 D sized NiCad batteries, or a small 6V lead-acid cell. Those do much better at high currents.

Comment: Unfortunately Nicads are obsolete and good cells are hard to get. AA Eneloops can handle 6A peak. Two packs in parallel should be OK.

Comment: NiCads are still the battery chemistry of choice for high current applications. NiMh cells are good too, but I would recommend D cells for such a high current application. As you say, 2 packs in parallel would help with the current demand, but even still, they won't last very long. From what I found online, Eneloops are good for a little less than an hour at 1 amp, and so you'll get less about 12 minutes from a single pack at 5 amps (double that for 2 packs in parallel)

Comment: Hmm ill look into that...... But just out of curiosity, is there like a prediction how long I can use the servo motor before it burned out. The servo is used only to drive 5 tendons to different fingers(Image can be seen above)

Comment: @PurnawanBrillian Don't force the servos into stall and they will last a long time. Use force feedback or a put a spring in the cord to ensure that the servo can move to its commanded position without 'buzzing'.